# Two anchor tags inside a single heading

Tags: html, seo, anchor, blogs, html-heading

I am working on a new blog's design and markup right now and I have found a place where I'm tempted to nest two anchor tags within a single heading tag:

```
<h3><a>Popular<a/>|<a>Recent</a></h3>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [autochemky.com](http://autochemky.com/tempo/PR.PNG))</sub>

The purpose of doing this would (obviously) be to enable "POPULAR" as a link to display popular articles and "RECENT" a link to display recent articles. . . clicking one or the other would only change the visible content (article list) on the sidebar and not link to a new page (either via ajax or having them both already loaded and one being a hidden div).

Doing this is a measure to avoid additional potentially unnecessary code involving more than one h3 element or more than one visible list of articles.

I suppose my questions to go along with this are (in order of importance and assuming HTML5):

**Is the markup valid/acceptable?**

**Would this have any realistic/noticeable effect on SEO?**

**Would you prefer to achieve the same result in a different way?**

Comment: my answer would be yes to the first one, and no to the next 2 questions, but what is your reason to put it into an h3 tag? you can just omit that and it'll be totally fine.

Comment: The h3 is because it is one of the sections in the sidebar and my sidebar sections are all headed by h3. I have seen some sites that use h2 and some that use h3, I chose h3.

Comment: makes sense. as daniel said, it shouldn't be a problem for SEO, and even if it is, it is a minor one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming HTML5 - it's acceptable, HTML5 introduced that any element can be inside an `<a>` tag (pretty sure)

> Changes in HTML5
>   Although previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “inline” content), the a element is now transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to also contain flow content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “block” content)—if the parent element of that instance of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain flow content.

Not a noticeable effect on SEO, it's a minor detail, as minor as you probably should be using a `<h1>` tag if that is the header of a section seeing as that is the base in the new HTML5 semantics.

I'd stick to what you have there definitely.

Comment: You are correct about the `<a>` tag thing (I've researched it), but this is the other way around since there are 2 `<a>` tags inside 1 `<h3>` tag. I know a single anchor has always been acceptable within a heading, I was just double checking about having 2.

Comment: Ah yes, either way though, 2 are the same as 1 (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, it's valid to have several `a` elements inside a heading (as long as you don't *nest* the `a` elements).

But I think your heading doesn't make sense. It's *either* "Popular" *or* "Recent", not both at the same time, right? So your heading is missing its purpose: describing the content of its section.

You should use a content toggler that is not part of the heading:

```
<section>
  <h1>Popular</h1>
  <nav>Or see <a href="#recent">recent content</a></nav>
  <ul>
    <li>…</li>
    <li>…</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

(If you wish, you could change the wording and style it that way that it looks like your example, by positioning the link to the other content next to the heading.)

Clicking at "recent content" should change the heading from "Popular" to "Recent", and changing the link to `<a href="#popular">popular content</a>`

If you don't use the URL anchor + CSS to hide/show the corresponding content, and you don't have a fallback for users/bots without JS, you should display both at the same time, popular and recent content, for users with disabled JavaScript.

---

Regarding:

> The `h3` is because it is one of the sections in the sidebar and my sidebar sections are all headed by `h3`. I have seen some sites that use `h2` and some that use `h3`, I chose `h3`.

Just to get sure: You are not free to use any heading level you like. You need to follow your document outline. If the use of `h3` is correct depends on your whole page structure.

Comment: I understand your perspective, but I think my thinking was more along the lines of 'popular and recent both represent articles, therefore they can share the same heading because its what they describe that is meaningful' I suppose perhaps not. Also as for the heading. . . how do you determine what header to use in your sidebar? I have it in the sidebar because h1 is reserved for the article title and h2 is reserved for sections of the article h3 for subsections. I determined that the sidebar content is less important h2 sections but more important in scope than h3 subsections. sound ok?

Comment: Regarding heading levels: Your outline is probably wrong (I'd need to see the whole markup, though). If you give your sidebar content a `h3`, it would be in scope of the ancesting `h2` (and therefor `h1`) of the article, which would be wrong. –– You need to start with `h1` for the whole page (typically site title) and `h2` for article title *and* navigation *and* sidebar. **Or** you use the sectioning elements (`section`, `article`, `nav`, `aside`), then your outline would be automatically correct (and you could always use `h1` or whatever you want).

Comment: Feel free to create a separate question regarding your outline, for example on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (and point me to it, here).